# use namespace with composer and silex

Tags: php, namespaces, composer-php, silex

I tried to load a class with composer and the class can't be found.

```
{
    "require": {
        "silex/silex": "~1.2",
        "twig/twig": ">=1.8,<2.0-dev",
        "symfony/twig-bridge": "~2.3",
        "knplabs/knp-menu": "~2.0",
        "symfony/form": "~2.3",
        "symfony/validator": "~2.3",
        "symfony/config": "~2.3",
        "symfony/translation": "~2.3",
        "symfony/locale": "~2.3",
        "symfony/security-csrf": "~2.4",
        "swiftmailer/swiftmailer": ">=4.1.2,<4.2-dev",
        "symfony/security": "~2.6"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "NewDanceStudio\\": "src/"
        }
   }
}
```

And in my src folder I've this structure :

- src

  - NewDanceStudio

    - DAO

      - SpikesDAO.php

My SpikesDAO file :

```
<?php

namespace NewDanceStudio\DAO;

class SpikesDAO {
    // class code
}
```

And in my `index.php` I've :

```
use NewDanceStudio\DAO\SpikesDAO;
```

And when I want to instanciate my classe I've a not found error

```
$sp = new SpikesDAO();
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try to change `"psr-0": { "NewDanceStudio\\": "src/" }` to `"psr-0": {"": "src/"}`.

Comment: put your whole index.php

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it can be useful :

If I include my class file without the namespace, I can instanciate it.

```
include __DIR__.'/../src/NewDanceStudio/DAO/SpikesDAO.php';
$p = new SpikesDAO();
```

**UPDATE 1**

The bug is resolved but I don't know why.

I've changed my composer.json to :

```
{
    "require": {
        "silex/silex": "~1.2",
        "twig/twig": ">=1.8,<2.0-dev",
        "symfony/twig-bridge": "~2.3",
        "knplabs/knp-menu": "~2.0",
        "symfony/form": "~2.3",
        "symfony/validator": "~2.3",
        "symfony/config": "~2.3",
        "symfony/translation": "~2.3",
        "symfony/locale": "~2.3",
        "symfony/security-csrf": "~2.4",
        "swiftmailer/swiftmailer": ">=4.1.2,<4.2-dev",
        "symfony/security": "~2.6"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "NewDanceStudio": ["src/"]
        }
   }
}
```